# Uniform distributions and stochastic dominance

Tags: statistics

I have two uniform distributions. In the first, $x\sim[0,1]$, and in the second $x\sim[0,2]$. Is it correct to say that the second distribution dominates the first by first order stochastic dominance, because $x\geq \frac{x}{2}$, $\forall x\in[0,2]$?

Thank you.

Comment: You may have overloaded $x$ as well as  missing  a step mentioning probabilities

Comment: @Henry Thank you. I have updated it now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1 \sim \mathcal U[0,2]$,$X_2 \sim \mathcal U[0,1]$.

**Conditions to satisfy:** For stochastic dominance, we have that $\forall y, P [X_1 \geq y]\ge P [X_2 \geq y]$, and $\exists y$ such that $P [X_1 \geq y]> P [X_2 \geq y]$.

Are these conditions satisfied?

**1) $\forall y, P [X_1 \geq y]\ge P [X_2 \geq y]$**

i) If $y\in(-\infty,0]\cup[2,\infty)$: then both $P [X_1 \geq y]=P [X_1 \geq y]$.

ii) If $y\in(0,1]$: then $P [X_2 \geq y]=(1-y)$, $P [X_1 \geq y]=(1-\frac{y}{2})$. Since $1-\frac{y}{2}>1-y$, $P [X_1 \geq y] > P [X_2 \geq y]$

iii) If $y\in(1,2)$: then $P [X_2 \geq y]=0$, $P [X_1 \geq y]=(1-\frac{y}{2})$. Since $1-\frac{y}{2}>0$, $P [X_1 \geq y] > P [X_2 \geq y]$

**2) $\exists y$ such that $P [X_1 \geq y]> P [X_2 \geq y]$**

We have already shown that for $y\in (0,2), P [X_1 \geq y] > P [X_2 \geq y]$